# How to use the non-member function lock

Tags: c++, concurrency

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

mutex m1;
mutex m2;

template<typename T>
void foo(const T& t){
    m1.lock();
    cout << t << '\n';
    m1.unlock();
}

int main(){
    thread t1{foo<string>,"lock m1"};
    unique_lock<mutex> lck1{m1,defer_lock};
    unique_lock<mutex> lck2{m2,defer_lock};
    lock(lck1,lck2);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The non-member function `lock` is designed to avoid deadlocks, right? Why my program is still deadlocked?

Comment: no lock is designed to prevent dead-locks.. locks are the reason of deadlocks! more over you example is highly inaccurate and unclear and I doubt it even compiles. post a valid - real example which you have checked it compiles and working

Comment: @DavidHaim I don't blame the OP for interpreting "[Locks the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock)" in that way.

Comment: @DavidHaim And aside from headers not being included and the OP using `using namespace std;` without including it in the question, it compiles, links and demonstrates the problem the OP is having. I've taken the liberty of editing the question to include the headers and using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is designed to avoid some specific types of deadlocks. It doesn't and cannot avoid deadlock entirely.

What a naïve implementation might do is simply lock `lck1`, and then `lck2`. If another thread simply locks `lck2`, and then locks `lck1`, you've got a potential deadlock. That's the scenario `std::lock` is designed to prevent. It will block if the locks cannot be acquired, but if one lock cannot be acquired, it won't hold any other lock.

Answer (score 4):

Here

```
lock(lck1,lck2);
t1.join();
```

you lock mutex `m1` and then waits for `t1` to complete.

In `t1` you also lock `m1` - here

```
m1.lock();
```

If `lock(lck1,lck2);` succeeds before `m1.lock();` you have a deadlock as `t1` will never complete because `main` has a lock on `m1`

If `m1.lock();` succeeds before `lock(lck1,lck2);` the program will execute fine.

However, you can't know which lock succeeds.